# Read Big Query table with Avro schema using beam, python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam, avro

I changed apache-beam SDK from 2.5.0 to 2.12.0 and got the Avro schema error when reading the table from Big Query in beam using python.

The BQ table has one TIMESTAMP field, others are STRING.

```py
data = pipe \
        | 'read bigquery' >> beam.io.Read(
            beam.io.BigQuerySource(
                dataset=args.dataset_name,
                table=args.table_name,
                use_standard_sql=True))
```

Error:

`SchemaParseException: Type property "[u'null', {u'logicalType': u'timestamp-micros', u'type': u'long'}]" not a valid Avro schema: Union item must be a valid Avro schema: Currently does not support timestamp-micros logical type`

Packages installed:

python=2.7.0, apache-beam=2.12.0, avro=1.9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regression in `avro` 1.9.0. The issue tracker for this is here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2429

If you are on python 2 you should be able to downgrade to 1.8.2 by doing `pip install "avro==1.8.2"`. If you are on python 3 I believe beam should try using `fastavro` by default (which should not have the bug you are running into).

Comment: Works like magic! Thank you. I use python 2, added my package versions to the description